# создать динамический список методов, или что это?

Tags: c#, wpf

только начинаю осваивать c#, нужно по работе
скачал такие таблицы live charts они компилируются в две библиотечки dll потом прилинковываются к wpf проекту и использутся.
пример на сайте был написан для winforms, я его переделал и воткнул в wpf с lrism

```
   <Wpf:CartesianChart Grid.Row="2" Series="{Binding LastHourSeries}" Hoverable="False" DataTooltip="{x:Null}" Margin="45,35,31,46" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="4">
        <Wpf:CartesianChart.AxisX>
            <!--a small visual improvement, lets hide the first points (x = 0, x=1) to get better animations-->
            <Wpf:Axis MinValue="2"/>
        </Wpf:CartesianChart.AxisX>
    </Wpf:CartesianChart
```

из кода видно, что данные берутся из модели

```
 public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        LastHourSeries = new SeriesCollection
        {
            new LineSeries
            {
                AreaLimit = -10,
                Values = new ChartValues<ObservableValue>
                {
                    new ObservableValue(3),
                    new ObservableValue(5),
                    new ObservableValue(6),
                    new ObservableValue(7),
                    new ObservableValue(3)
                }
            }
        };
```

где каждая точка графика задается как новый экземпляр обекта new ObservableValue(int arg);
хотелось бя узнать ,как их можно задавать динамически
вот класс библиотеки который их описывает

```
 public class ObservableValue : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private double _value;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of ObservableValue class
    /// </summary>
    public ObservableValue()
    {

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of ObservableValue class with a given value
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value"></param>
    public ObservableValue(double value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Value in he chart
    /// </summary>
    public double Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set
        {
            _value = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Value");
        }
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChangedImplementation

    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs when a property value changes.
    /// </summary>
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    /// <summary>
    /// Called when [property changed].
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="propertyName">Name of the property.</param>
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    #endregion
}
```

}

введите сюда код

Comment: в чем вопрос то?

Comment: У них такая документация, ну чтож вы! Вот вам про [ObservableValue](https://lvcharts.net/App/examples/v1/wpf/Observable%20Point), а вот вам [базовая реализация](https://lvcharts.net/App/examples/v1/wpf/Series), где вам достаточно в коллекцию добавить новый объект.

Comment: Вопрос в том, как значения задавать динамически, то есть туда записывать данные из вне, а-то во всех примерах уже есть список точек, а как эти точки можно сделать из например массива или списка простого, который у меня например из базы данных берется

Comment: EvgeniyZ, базовая реализация, как раз походе на то, что крутится у меня в голове, благодарю...